# EF Core Contains unable to be translated

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq

The following query can't be translated, and I can't really understand why something this simple, can't be done!

What's causing the problem here, is the contains giving. I need to use a combination of both `LoginProvider` and `ProviderKey` to map to a specific user.

`uniqueUsers` is just a list of `EntityUserIdentityProvider`.

```cs
 var userProviders = _userLoginRepository.GetAll()
                     .Where(ul => uniqueUsers.Contains(new EntityUserIdentityProvider(ul.LoginProvider, ul.ProviderKey)))
                     .Select(ul => new
                     {
                         Provider = new EntityUserIdentityProvider(ul.LoginProvider, ul.ProviderKey),
                         ul.UserId,
                     }).ToList()
                     .ToDictionary(k => k.Provider, v => v.UserId);
```

Comment: C# is a language of types. Knowing the exact types is important. Assuming `List<EntityUserIdentityProvider> uniqueUsers` and that `EntityUserIdentityProvider` doesn't implement `IEquatable<T>` (which wouldn't translate to SQL anyway) than `Contains` is just reference equality, which means a `new EntityUserIdentityProvider` can never be considered in the `List<T>`, so the condition is always false. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

You are currently trying to use `Contains` method to match 2 properties (LoginProvider and ProviderKey), which is not supported in Entity Framework. It only works with 1 property due to the way the SQL is generated.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/)

This library is not free, but the [WhereBulkContains](https://entityframework-extensions.net/where-bulk-contains) method does exactly what you want:

```
var userProviders = _userLoginRepository.GetAll()
             .WhereBulkContains(uniqueUsers, ul => new { ul.LoginProvider, ul.ProviderKey })
             //.Where(ul => uniqueUsers.Contains(new EntityUserIdentityProvider(ul.LoginProvider, ul.ProviderKey)))
             .Select(ul => new
             {
                 Provider = new EntityUserIdentityProvider(ul.LoginProvider, ul.ProviderKey),
                 ul.UserId,
             }).ToList()
             .ToDictionary(k => k.Provider, v => v.UserId);
```

Under the hood, we usually create a temporary table and create a `JOIN` statement with your key if you want to create the code on your side to make it work without our library.